# Копирование масивов

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите, как с помощью циклов (или цикла) сделать копирование элементов из одного массива в два. Последовательно - когда первый заполнится,
остальные элементы занести во второй.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копируем из массива А в B и С. Проходишь первым циклом

```
for (var i =0; i < B.length; i++) { 
   B[i]=A[i]
}
```

Затем от

```
for(var j = B.length, j < A.length,  k++) {
   C[j] = A[j]
}
```

Comment: А если покучерявей (не проверяя проблемы нехватки длины второго массива):

        int[] A1, A2, B, ar;

.............

        ar = A1;
        for(int i=0, j=0; i < B.length; ) {
            if(j >= ar.length) {
                j = 0;
                ar = A2;
            }
            ar[j++] = B[i++];
        }

Answer (score 3):

Если предположить, что `A.leght >= B.lenght + C.lenght`, то

```
System.arraycopy(A, 0, B, 0, B.length());
System.arraycopy(A, B.length(), C, 0, C.lenght());
```

если нет, то нужно немного помучиться.

```
if (A.length() < B.length())
    System.arraycopy(A, 0, B, 0, A.length); // A.lenght < B.length. C - не при делах.
else {
    System.arraycopy(A, 0, B, 0, B.length());
    int size = Math.min(C.length(), A.length()-B.length();
    System.arraycopy(A, B.length(), C, 0, size);
}
```

А копировать через цикл - печально.  В некоторых случаях - в 5-10 раз падение производительности.

Comment: боюсь, что это учебное задание. Жестокое и беспощадное

За ответ конечно +, тоже вспомнил этот метод, но писать не стал

Comment: именно учебное, через arraycopy нельзя))

Comment: даже если это учебное задание, нужно использовать arraycopy. Но если преподаватель не понимает юмор, то можно добавить реализацию отдельно

void arraycopy(Object source, int spos, Object dest, int dpos, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i< size; i++)
    dest[dpos+i] = source[spos + i];
}
 (ну и в коде убрать `System.`)

Использование отдельного метода - красивый и правильный ход.

Comment: > через arraycopy нельзя))
потому и назвал жестоким и беспощадным. Обучение классам тоже обычно на адовых и нереалистичных примерах, к сожалению